# Distribution of a multivariate normal conditional on its norm.

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Let $X \sim N(0,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is a $p\times p$ covariance matrix. What is the distribution of $X$ conditional on $||X||_2 = t$,  $t>1$.

Comment: Conditional $\|X\|_2=t$, the random variable $X$ is distributed on the sphere of radius $t$. If $\Sigma$ is the identity, then this distribution is uniform (due to rotational invariance). What do you want to know about this distribution?

Comment: The conditional probability density function.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there. As a final comment from my side, the density with respect to the Lebesgue measure does not exist, so your density will be with respect to the Haar measure or Hausdorff measure.